# pip package installs okay but cannot be run

Tags: python, pip, installation, debian-based

I am wanting to install a pip package on Debian but when I install it using

```
pip install bitmex-market-maker
```

or

```
pip install --user bitmex-market-maker
```

it doesn't work and gives me

```
-bash: marketmaker: command not found
```

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6KCR.png)
  it works fine on my MacBook
I tried to reinstall reboot and even tried pip3 to no avail.

Comment: Hello, how you been? Can you add a picture of the error?

Comment: okay i will edit

Comment: `pip show --files bitmex-market-maker` to see where it's installed.

Comment: Your question a bit confusing. Sounds like it fails to install. Is `marketmaker` executable? Have you tried running it with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the libraries you first need to be inside the python environment.

At your terminal try:

```
python -m marketmaker
```